# Call the controller when combo box selection occurs

Tags: angularjs

I have set of tabs and a combo box(for time frame) in top.html file , which loads in all pages.

I am rendering the pages according to tabs selected using angular JS.

I want the view to update when time frame is changed using the combo box , i.e to call respective controller of that page.

**I have no clue what page is currently rendered as the combo box is in different file.**

Is there any way of invoking the controller on event change ?

Answer (score 0):

use respective event and call the method of controller. For example you can call controller method on click event using ng-click,and similarly so on.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: The problem is i dont know which controller to call.Page is rendered dynamically at run-time